# How to convert date to milliseconds since 1970 using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have these variables:  (not literally, but this is what I obtain from a datepicker)

```
var StartMonth = "April";
var StartDate = "21";
var CurrentStartTime = "2"; 
var CurrentEndTime = "5";
var Startampm = "PM"; //corresponds to the CurrentStartTime
var Endampm = "PM"; //corresponds to the CurrentEndTime
```

I need to convert these variables to a single variable, milliseconds since 1970.

Comment: -1 For "send me teh codez" kind of question

Comment: See example 1 on this page http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp

Comment: hahaha
sometimes I just get lazy, -1 me plz

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class.

Comment: Super vague answer

Comment: It's not a valid answer

Comment: Sure, I wish I could simply delete this answer, but because it's been accepted, I can't (the server won't let me). If I were to edit this answer to expand it, it would end up being basically identical to the top answer, which wouldn't be fair. So, this answer shall remain languishing at the bottom. Sorry.

Answer (score 24):

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vv85G/)**

Here is a simple way to do this using the `valueOf` method of `Date`.

```
var d = new Date();
var millisecondsSince1970 = d.valueOf();
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `getTime()` method of Date object to get milliseconds since epoch.

```
var date = new Date();
var dt = date.getTime();
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply make use of implicit conversions like this:

```
+new Date()
```

Comment: That's not a good option.  It obfuscates your code and makes it difficult to maintain over time.  I'm always a fan of simplifying code, but you still have to keep it readable!

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to a date using *new Date(args)*, then use *Date.prototype.getTime*, or just convert the date to a number. It's all in ECMA-262 §15.9.